# TS2345 sequelize create function

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am creating a sequelize repository and I have an object which extends sequelize model.

I was able to do the following to save the model to the db.

```
repository.create(myModel) // myModel being an instance of MyModel which extends sequelize model
```

Now I am getting the following error in typescript:

```
Argument of type 'MyModel' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreationAttributes<MyModel>'.
  Type 'MyModel' is not assignable to type 'Omit<any, string>'.
    Index signature for type 'number' is missing in type 'MyModel'.ts(2345)
```

I was doing some searching and a suggestion was to add to MyModel:

```
[key: number]: number;
```

When I do that the error is changed to the following:

```
Argument of type 'MyModel' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreationAttributes<MyModel>'.
  Type 'MyModel' is not assignable to type 'Omit<any, string>'.
    Index signature for type 'symbol' is missing in type 'MyModel'.ts(2345)
```

I can get around the error by changing the call to create:

```
repository.create({...myModel})
```

Can anyone point me to documentation about `ts(2345)` what it is, perhaps how to ignore it. Or even solve the issue the correct way?

Using the spread operator, to me seems a bit messy, but if that is the correct solution that is fine.

Model definition:

```
import {
  Column, DataType, ForeignKey, Model, Sequelize, Table,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';
import MediaResource from './media_resource';
import User from './users';

@Table({
  tableName: 'videos',
  timestamps: true,
  version: true,
})
export default class Video extends Model {
  @Column({
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.literal("nextval('videos_id_seq'::regclass)"),
  })
  id?: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => MediaResource)
  @Column({
    field: 'media_resource_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
  })
  mediaResourceId?: number;

  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.STRING(191),
  })
  title?: string;

  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.STRING(2000),
  })
  url?: string;

  @Column({
    allowNull: true,
    type: DataType.STRING(512),
  })
  description?: string;

  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.BOOLEAN,
  })
  is_3d?: boolean;

  @Column({
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.BOOLEAN,
  })
  is_360?: boolean;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column({
    field: 'user_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
  })
  userId?: number;

  @Column({
    field: 'created_at',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.DATE,
  })
  createdAt?: Date;

  @Column({
    field: 'updated_at',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataType.DATE,
  })
  updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

Repository create signiture:

```
const db = DB.getInstance();
const videosRepository = db.getRepository(Video);
const transaction = await db.transaction();

try {
  const saved = await videosRepository.create({ ...video }, { transaction });
await transaction.commit();
return saved;
} catch (err) {
  await transaction.rollback();
  if (err instanceof Error) logger.error(err.message);
  throw new InternalServerError();
}
```

We have a sequelize singleton which is what db is, the video object is created from an express request body.

Also this used to work, I could add a ts-ignore comment and it will work.

sequelize: 6.15.1
sequelize-typescript: 2.1.2
typescript: 4.5.5

Comment: Can you show model definition and `repository.create` signature

Comment: I updated the question, thanks for looking.

Comment: I see only the content of `create` and don't see parameters

Comment: Did you find the cause of this error?

Answer (score 5):

So I've come across 2 solutions to this problem, the first is as outlined above:

`repository.create({ ...myModel })`

And the second is:

`repository.create(myModel as any)`

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution ...
`export default class Video extends Model<InferAttributes<Video>, InferCreationAttributes<Video>> {`

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).