# How can I get suggestions (autocompletion) for sequelize classes extending the Model class?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js

I have a post class defined as

```
@Table
class Post extends Model {
    @Column
    declare imgUrl: string

    @Column
    declare userId: string

    @Column
    declare username: string
    
    @Column
    declare profileImgUrl: string
}
```

But when I go to actually type out the fields I always find myself having to look back at the source code of the model and leads to a lot of errors as I forget fields

```
  const post = new Post({
    imgUrl: 'http://localhost/image.png',
    profileImgUrl: 'http://localhost/image.png',
    username: 'johnsmith',
  })
```

In this example, I didn't specify all the fields yet I didn't get an error from vscode

So my question is, what would I have to do for it to show all the fields when I hover over the class and give errors when I forget fields so I dont have to always look back at the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your `class Post extends Model` to `class Post extends Model<Post>`.

See the declaration of the Model class in the source code at https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/packages/core/src/model.d.ts:

```
export abstract class Model<TModelAttributes extends {} = any, TCreationAttributes extends {} = TModelAttributes>
  extends ModelTypeScript {
  //...
  /**
   * Builds a new model instance.
   *
   * @param values an object of key value pairs
   * @param options instance construction options
   */
  constructor(values?: MakeNullishOptional<TCreationAttributes>, options?: BuildOptions);
  // ...
}
```

Ie. Pass the `Post` class itself as the generics argument to the `TModelAttributes` generics parameter.

I can repro this with the following extracted parts of the sequelize.js library:

```
type PartialBy<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>>;

type NullishPropertiesOf<T> = {
   [P in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[P] ? P
     : null extends T[P] ? P
       : never
 }[keyof T];

type MakeNullishOptional<T extends object> = PartialBy<T, NullishPropertiesOf<T>>;

class Model<TModelAttributes extends {} = any, TCreationAttributes extends {} = TModelAttributes> {
   constructor(values?: MakeNullishOptional<TCreationAttributes>) {}
}

class Post extends Model<Post> {
   declare imgUrl: string;
   declare userId: string;
}

new Post({
  // fill in the fields
});
```

It gives you the behaviour you want: VS Code suggestions (AKA autocomplete) in the argument to the `Post` constructor call suggest the fields declared above for your `Post` class, and if you don't fill in all the fields, it will give an error such as (when none of the fields are filled in):

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MakeNullishOptional<Post>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Omit<Post, never>': imgUrl, userId
```

For the other types I pulled from the library for this repro, see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/packages/core/src/utils/types.ts.

You may also want to read about the `InferAttributes` and `InferCreationAttributes`, which you can use like `extends Model<InferAttributes<Foo>, InferCreationAttributes<Foo>>`.

---

As for the other part of your question:

> what would I have to do for it to show all the fields when I hover over the class

You can do this by adding a documentation comment to your `Post` class like

```
/**
 * Documentation comment lorem ipsum ...
 */
@Table
class Post extends Model {
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped solved my problem. I came across another error when doing this because I also needed to add this to the class https://stackoverflow.com/a/71143454/19729750

Comment: updated post to point to `InferAttributes` and `InferCreationAttributes` :)